# Safe Password Characters for Asp.Net MVC RegEx Validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

What characters are considered safe for passwords in a ASP.NET MVC4 application?  And what is the correct way to validate the value?  I've been trying to use alphanumeric characters plus several simple characters.  Unfortunately, I am running into problems with the RegEx not firing.

The characters I am allowing are:

```
!@#$%&+
```

The validation attribute and RegEx I am using is:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&+]*$")]
```

Comment: IMO any character is safe for a password as long as it isn't modified by browsers during the POST method (which as far as I am aware is none).  Why?  Because most secure systems will store a hashed value, and never display the original value so it doesn't really matter as long as the user can type it.

Comment: I agree that allowing any character in the password is perfectly good, I have found that I get fewer user "password problems" If I strip the trailing whitespace from the password everytime it is entered. If a user does this intentionly, this causes no problems, but since people do see a significance significant different with trailing whitespace, they don't understand why their password is not valid. And AMEN to using a storing salted hash.

Comment: There'll be plenty of users who have awfully simple passwords, but a good number who'll choose, or want to choose, the most obscure characters permissible, and there's no reason not to let them do that.

Answer (score 2):

> What characters are considered safe for passwords in a ASP.NET MVC4 application?

All of them.

Do you have a good reason for implementing such a rule?

Encourage your users to choose a long and not-too-complex password. You can give them feedback with a [password strength indicator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19245/Google-Password-Strength-API).

While we're talking about password strength, this XKCD comic is relevant:

[image]